# Не могу установить магазин laravel: techstar-ecommerce

Tags: laravel

Делал все по инструкции: https://github.com/techstar-cloud/techstar-ecommerce. при установке возникли ошибки:

```
Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateAddressesTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_11_130736_create_addresses_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130736_create_addresses_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateCategoriesTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130617_create_categories_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130817_create_categories_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateProductDetailsTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130757_create_product_details_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130917_create_product_details_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateProductOffersTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130756_create_product_offers_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_130946_create_product_offers_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateActionTypesTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_131111_create_action_types_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_15_131317_create_action_types_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateTypePreferencesTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_10_154443_create_type_preferences_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_16_154443_create_type_preferences_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreatePersonsTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_10_154509_create_persons_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_16_154509_create_persons_table.php", the first will be used.
Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "CreateBussinessTable" was found in both "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_10_154538_create_bussiness_table.php" and "D:/OSPanel/domains/multi/database/migrations/2016_11_16_154538_create_bussiness_table.php", the first will be used.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\ServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

установил класс:

```
composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs
```

получил следующую серию:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.7.0
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.39
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.38
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.37
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.36
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.35
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.34
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.33
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.32
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.31
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.30
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.29
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.28
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.27
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.26
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.25
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.24
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.23
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.22
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.21
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.20
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.3
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.6.0
    - Installation request for davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs ^5.2 -> satisfiable by davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs[5.2.0].
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs 5.2.0 requires illuminate/view 5.6.*|5.7.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.18, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.12, v5.7.2, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9], illuminate/view[v5.6.0, v5.6.1, v5.6.10, v5.6.11, v5.6.12, v5.6.13, v5.6.14, v5.6.15, v5.6.16, v5.6.17, v5.6.19, v5.6.2, v5.6.20, v5.6.21, v5.6.22, v5.6.23, v5.6.24, v5.6.25, v5.6.26, v5.6.27, v5.6.28, v5.6.29, v5.6.3, v5.6.30, v5.6.31, v5.6.32, v5.6.33, v5.6.34, v5.6.35, v5.6.36, v5.6.37, v5.6.38, v5.6.39, v5.6.4, v5.6.5, v5.6.6, v5.6.7, v5.6.8, v5.6.9, v5.7.0, v5.7.1, v5.7.10, v5.7.11, v5.7.2, v5.7.3, v5.7.4, v5.7.5, v5.7.6, v5.7.7, v5.7.8, v5.7.9].
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.12|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.14|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.15|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.16|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.17|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.20|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.22|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.23|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.29|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.30|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.32|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.33|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.34|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.35|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.36|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.37|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.38|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.39|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.6.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.10|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.11|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.2|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.3|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.4|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.5|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.8|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - don't install illuminate/view v5.7.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.5.44
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.5.44, required as ^5.4) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.5.44].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

PS. Или Посоветуйте хороший код для разбора магазина. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

composer require davejamesmiller/laravel-breadcrumbs требует версию ниже laravel 5.6, так что пакет этот древний и разрабы на него походу забили

Comment: Друзья подскажите пакеты по новее, для обучения... Спасибо :)